# No color emojis Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, emoji

So,I upgraded to 18.04 but  i cant use the color emojis i tried making a folder and adding a emoji to it but its black and white and doesnt even work with any text editor any idea how to get around this?

Comment: I notice this too. I run Kubuntu 18.04 as well and the color emojis show up in Nautilus but not dolphin, where it shows black and white ones. However my default file manager is Nautilus so this does not effect me as much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to 
[this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-meta/+bug/1767390),
the logic behind Kubuntu not "supporting" color emoji is that Qt doesn't fully support them. The reason that some apps show them (like Nautilus) is because they are GTK+ apps or something else that fully supports color emoji.